# Laravel routes are not working only root route is working

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have cloned my laravel project on EC2 instance (type ubuntu 16.04)
after that I have run `composer install` command

I have changed `/etc/nginx/site-available/default` config as per my local machin which is

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/myproject/public;

    charset utf-8;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name myServerIpAddress;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }


    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Now when I open my server ip address it show my `/` route correctly but when I tried to open `/login` or `/register` it shows me 404 not found

my nginx version is (1.10.0)
my php version is (7.0.18)

I have also checked the log files but it is not showing me any error

Thank You

Comment: Did you follow the instruction here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/#web-server-configuration?

Comment: Oh god, Thank it worked. Just curious why this config is working on my local environment. Anyways I will figure out later. Thanks once again

Answer (score 4):

With your current configuration, upon a request to `/login`, nginx will try to see if a file called `/var/www/html/myproject/public/login` exists, then if a folder called `/var/www/html/myproject/public/login/` exists and then return an error 404 if none of them exists.

This is not what you expect since you did not created a file called `login`, you just created a route inside Laravel's router. Thus, you have to configure nginx in a way that it will call the `index.php` file of the public directory at each request to this *vhost*, and the framework will then be able to compare the URL targeted by the request with the routes you registered.

[As documented on Laravel's website](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/#web-server-configuration), you should edit your configuration to add the following *location* block in order to redirect all the requests (excepted the ones to static resources) to `index.php`, with the original query as parameter:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```